# typescript error - type string cant be used to index object

Tags: typescript, express, types, busboy

I'm still pretty noob to typescript. I'm trying to get busboy working on my server. I have this block of code that gives me the error.

```
 const bb = busboy({ headers: req.headers });
   
 const uploads = {};
 const tmpdir = os.tmpdir();
 const fields = {}

 bb.on("field", (fieldname, val) => {
     fields[fieldname] = val
   console.log(`Processed field ${fieldname}: ${val}.`);
 });
```

the ts error im getting is on `fields[fieldname]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare the variable `const fields = {};`, Typescript infers the type to object.

To fix your issue, you need to define a type of your variable explicitly.

```
const fields: Record<string, string> = {};
```